# How do I write a regular expression to get valid Facebook names between <li> elements?

Tags: html, regex, parsing

For example, I want `George W. Bush` and `Barry Obama` from

```
<li>George W. Bush</li>
<li>Barry Obama</li>
```

According to Facebook,

> Usernames can only contain alphanumeric characters (A-Z, 0-9) or a
>   period (".")

so what I want is a regular expression that looks for `<li>` followed by a valid Facebook username followed by `</li>`.

Comment: Better use DOM manipulations to extract the name, if this is string use `/<li>([a-zA-Z0-9. ]+)<\/li>/`

Comment: This HTML is a text file that I'm reading on a desktop application. So I don't access to JQuery or whatever

Comment: There are many frameworks which give you access to the DOM on the command line.  Search for `xpath` for a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I would try to keep it simple. This should work for what you need.

```
(?<=<li>).*?(?=<\/li>)
```